# how to set in each function to index one items only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, append, blogger

developer's

i am trying to fix the jquery code to fix unwanted each(function) items

here is code

```
 $(".HTML,.list-grid .HTML .widget-content").each(function() {
            var v = $(this),
// up too so.......on

text = 'View All',
                    aa = 'tag";
                     $(".HTML").each(function() {
                            var div = $(this);
                            div.append(aa)
                        })
});
        //up to so............on
```

is there any solution to stop this multiple index of these lines i have attached in above image

any tag or code available to use in this **

```
.each(function() {
                    var div = $(this);
                    div.append(aa)
```

**

so that this error can fixed

Comment: I've read it few times and have no idea what is your goal and what is your problem

Answer (score 0):

After several times reading and trying to understand the problem, I could understand that you only need one anchor tag. If this is the case then the solutions is that you'd definitely need to get the tag creation process outside the `.each()` function, so that it will not be created again and again as much as the elements you have.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
$(".b-grid-item .HTML .widget-content,.list-grid .HTML .widget-content").each(function() {
  var v = $(this),
      // up too so.......on

      text = 'View All',
      bb = '<a class="b-grid-viewmore" href="/search?&max-result=8">' + text + "</a>";

  v.closest('.HTML').find('.widget-title').append(bb);
});
```

Comment: this tag is working but problem is still same it index 3-5 ancher links below i have added full code